# Change color of a label in a Magento form

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, forms, adminform

I have a simple question, I know how to change an the color of an field in a magento form but my problem is i didn't know how to change the color of the label associate to it.

here is an image :

[image: color field]

and here is my code :

```
$fieldset->addField('modeleChoix', 'select', array(

        'label' => 'Modele selection(only update)',

        'name' => 'modeleChoix',

        'style' => 'color:red',

        'values' => $tableau2,

        'onchange' => 'majChampModele()',

    ));
```

Comment: Do you want some thing like https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BweKwHQ_asV2S2VnMmRzTk5hM3c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Magento does not provide an out of the box method to change the style of the label.

See the `getLabelHtml` method from `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract` :

```
public function getLabelHtml($idSuffix = '')
{
    if (!is_null($this->getLabel())) {
        $html = '<label for="'.$this->getHtmlId() . $idSuffix . '">' . $this->_escape($this->getLabel())
              . ( $this->getRequired() ? ' <span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</label>' . "\n";
    } else {
        $html = '';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

I guess the only way you can do it is by creating your own renderer that extends `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Select` and rewrites that methods to add the style attribute to the label element.

An alternative would be to use JavaScript to change the style on the fly but that's kind of hacky.

Answer (score 2):

Their are two solution for this.

1) if you inspect any admin form their will be a `<div>` under a `<form>` which contains a id which is i think generated based on tab name and section name which you have used in your form creation process. for ex `faq_tabs_form_section_content`

By using this id you can create a css rule for a label. which will be like

```
#faq_tabs_form_section_content label {
    color: #CB1D1D !important;
}
```

create this rule in any existing css or create a new css. i used the existing one `skin\adminhtml\default\default\reset.css`

**Note:** this will change a color of all labels of that form.

2) If you want to change a color for a particular label only.

When you create a field for a form by using a code some thing like

```
$fieldset->addField(
            "customer_name", "text", array(
            "label" => Mage::helper("test_faq")->__("Customer Name"),
            "name" => "customer_name",
            'required' => true,
            )
        );
```

Add `'container_id' => 'customeCustomerName',` into this declaration will create a id of that `<tr>`. On which basis you can create a css rule.

so your declaration becomes like.

```
$fieldset->addField(
            "customer_name", "text", array(
            "label" => Mage::helper("test_faq")->__("Customer Name"),
            "name" => "customer_name",
            'required' => true,
            'container_id' => 'customeCustomerName',
            )
        );
```

and the css rule will be

```
#customeCustomerName label{
color: #440088 !important;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold;
```

}

and your result will be like.

[image]

Hope this helps you.